# How to manipulate the value of a char pointer from a external function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, parameters

I'm intending to create a function that has a similar job of the scanf, but that I will not need to define the length of my char array, only defining the pointer ( and using malloc() ).

At this point, I want to make this header file to only have to include and use it when I need.

Here is my external function, inside of `string.variavel.h`:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

void pegastr( char *str ){

    char x , *guardaStr ;
    unsigned int i , j ;

    str = malloc( 1 );
    str[0] = '\0';

    for( j = 0 ; x != '\n' ; ++j ){

        x = getc( stdin );
        fflush( stdin );

        guardaStr = malloc( j );

        for( i = 0 ; i < j ; ++i ){
            guardaStr[i] = str[i];
        }

        str = malloc( 1 + j );

        for ( i = 0 ; i < j + 1 ; ++i ){
            if( guardaStr[i] == '\0' ){
                str[i] = x ;
            }else{
                str[i] = guardaStr[i] ;
            }
        }
        str[i] = '\0';
    }
}
```

And here is my function that calls and include the externals:

```
# include "string.variavel.h"

int main(void){

    char *palavrao , *torrada;

    pegastr( palavrao );

    pegastr( torrada );

    printf( "%s\n%s" , palavrao , torrada );

    return 0;
}
```

So, my problem is that if I copy all code of `pegastr()` to inside of main(), when I try to output the string it works, but, if I don't do this and let the code stays like it is right now, when I try to output the value of the strings inside the main(), I only gets (null) at each printf().

I think that my problem is with the address that I send/receive to/from the parameters of my function `pegastr()`, but I don't see what I need to change more.

My thanks for all of your help!

Comment: `fflush( stdin );` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Pass a pointer to the value you want to modify. This should be covered in any introductory book

Comment: You massive memory leaks but that doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: You also access uninitialized memory which is undefined behavior

Comment: I'll suggest that you read about `realloc`. With `realloc` you can achieve the goal in a much easier way.

Answer (score 1):

The code you pasted has a lots of problems with memory handling. You have memory leaks and what you do there is not very clear.

I'm going to address the main problem you have here, from what I understood after reading your question. This is generally about pointers and how they work.

If you want to allocate a pointer in a function and return it, you can A) pass a pointer to the pointer or B) return the pointer.

A)

```
// call: myallocator(&element, size)
void myallocator(char **element, size_t size)
{
    *element = malloc(size);
    // ...
}
```

B)

```
// call: element = myallocator(size)
char* myallocator(size_t size)
{
    char *mem;

    mem = malloc(size);
    // ...

    return mem;
}
```

Comment: My thanks! My problem was the functions for memory manipulation that I was using... I didn't know the existence of realloc and the memory leaking that I was doing

Answer (score 0):

If I copy all your code into `main`, it still just prints the `null`. In general your program has undefined behavior and won't work (regardless of where you put the code)

Your first problem is that the function **does not** change the value of `palavrao` and `torrada`. The function is just called with the **value** of the pointers and no matter how much you change the value inside the function, the variables outside still have the same value.

Instead you can do it like:

```
 void pegastr( char **str ){  // Note double pointer
      ....
      *str = malloc(....
 }

 // Called like
 pegastr( &palavrao );
```

or like

```
char* pegastr(){  // Return the malloc'ed pointer
      char * tmp = malloc(....

      ....

      return tmp;
 }


 // Called like

 palavrao = pegastr();
```

Besides that your code have quite a number of things you need to fix:

```
    for( j = 0 ; x != '\n' ; ++j ){
                 ^
                 x is uninitialized when the loop starts
```

and

```
        guardaStr = malloc( j );
                            ^
                            Do you want this when j is 0 ?
                            Or do you really want j + 1 here ?
```

Further you you have memory leak when you run this code the 2nd, 3rd, ... time. You need to free the memory before overwrint the old pointer with a new pointer.

The memory leak also applies to:

```
         str = malloc( 1 + j );
```

And here:

```
        if( guardaStr[i] == '\0' ){
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^
            Access outside allocated memory (e.g. when j is 0)
```

I'll suggest that you read about `realloc` - it is a better choice for your code.

Using `realloc` the code could be something like:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

void pegastr( char **str ){

    char *tmp;
    char x;
    unsigned int j ;

    tmp = malloc( 1 );
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
        // Out of memory
        exit(1);
    }
    str[0] = '\0';

   j = 1; // Notice: j starts from 1
    while(1){

        x = getc( stdin );
        if (x == '\n')
        {
            // Don't copy the \n - just break the loop
            break;
        }
        fflush( stdin );

        // Insert the new char and a termination
        tmp = realloc(tmp, j+1);
        if (tmp == NULL)
        {
            // Out of memory
            exit(1);
        }
        tmp[j-1] = x;
        tmp[j] = '\0';

        // Increment j
        ++j;
    }

    // Update the input pointers value
    *str = tmp;
}



int main(void){

    char *palavrao , *torrada;

    pegastr( &palavrao );

    pegastr( &torrada );

    printf( "%s\n%s\n" , palavrao , torrada );

    free(palavrao);
    free(torrada);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: My thanks! I'm still having a doubt: When I call `pegastr()` again, the addres that `**str` pointers to is overwrited? (So, if this is right, this doesn't will gives me a memory leaking, gives it?). And the purpose of `free()` the `main()`'s pointers is for leave only those address or it will leave the pointers inside the `pegastr()` too?!